# Compare table with a table variable in a Stored procedure in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to compare a table against a table variable in a Stored Procedure? Normally to compare the two tables we used this query:

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM Table A 
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM Table B 
                  WHERE Table A.ID = Table B.ID)
```

But here, I have `Table A` and one table variable `@Item` like Table B.

In this scenario, how to compare `Table A` and `@Item`?

I am writing one stored procedure, in that stored procedure I want to compare the existing one table with the table variable which is generated from the front end and passed as a XML dataset to the Stored Procedure...
In that, if all the rows in the table variable @Item presents in the existing table then it returns true else false...

Any suggestions please....

Comment: Just a minor clarification - `@item` would be a _table variable_, while a _temp table_ would be `#item` or `##item` depending on scope.

Comment: yes. it is a table variable. sorry for not defining it clearly.

Comment: @thevan- Try with join as well. It will speed up your query. Below is my answer :) !

Comment: @SQL: Yes It also gives the desired result.

Comment: Result will be the same, But, I just want to emphasize on Joins for the performance point of view

Comment: @SQL: OK. In all the answers below. I learnt some new things. I thank u all.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If works just the same (altough using table aliases will make it easier)

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Item sub 
    WHERE Table A.ID = sub.ID
)
```

Comment: I tried like this
SELECT * FROM @Item AS ItemTable WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM PUR_POIndent WHERE PUR_POIndent.POID = ItemTable.POID). But it throws invalid column POID

Comment: Then you must not have a POID column on either @Item or PUR_POIndent

Answer (score 4):

I've always preferred the left-join syntax when excluding the results of one table:

```
select a.*
from [table] a
    left outer join @item b
        on a.ID = b.ID
where b.ID is null
```

I suspect the query plan should come out the same though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the subquery, you can do the same sort of thing

```
select *
from tableA
where not in(
 select b.ID
 from @tableB)
```

the `@tableB` is just a table value parameter, rather than a temporary table. Its a variable that holds a table in it, so it can be passed between functions.

you might also be able to do something like:

```
select *
from tableA a
left outer join @tableB b
on a.ID = b.ID
where b.ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference the table variable just like a normal table:

```
SELECT * FROM Table A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @ITEM WHERE Table A.ID = @ITEM.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare entire tables, and the schemas are guaranteed identical you can use `EXCEPT`.

```
SELECT *, 'New row' [Edit] FROM [Table A]
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM @Item

UNION ALL

SELECT *, 'Deleted row' FROM @Item
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM [Table A]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also try below using [**Joins**](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/) as well.

```
SELECT * FROM Table A 
Left Join @Item sub on A.ID = sub.ID
Where sub.ID is Null
```